# Assumptions in mathematica when Symplify on Log[Exp[a/b]]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions, logic

In mathematica 9.0:

This:

```
Assuming[b > 0 || b < 0, Simplify[Log[Exp[a/b]]]]
```

yields:

```
a/b
```

However, this:

```
Assuming[FullSimplify[b > 0 || b < 0], Simplify[Log[Exp[a/b]]]]
enter code here
```

or this:

```
Assuming[b !=0 , Simplify[Log[Exp[a/b]]]]
```

Yield:

```
Log[Exp[a/b]]
```

Shouldn't be both equivalent? Why isn't the expression simplified in the second case?. Also tried to add ass an assumption a and b to be real, just in case, but doesn't work either.  Could someone shed any light on this?

Comment: I evaluated `Assuming[b > 0 || b < 0, Simplify[Log[Exp[a/b]]]]` in `Mathematica` ver.`7`, `8` and `9` runing `Windows`. I get always `Log[Exp[a/b]]]`, never `a/b` as you claim. What version do you use?

Comment: `FullSimplify[Log[Exp[a/b]], 
 Assumptions -> {a \[Element] Reals, b > 0}]` gives `a/b` in v9 but original formulation gives `Log[Exp[a/b]`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this has to do with the assumption `b > 0` implicitly stating that `b` is a real, where that is not the case with `b != 0`.  This is, of course, because there is no natural ordering of complex numbers, but they do have a `0`-element to compare against.  As evidence for this answer, note that

```
Assuming[Element[b, Reals] && b != 0, Simplify[Log[Exp[a/b]]]]
```

Gives the expected result of `a/b` where it didn't above.

Comment: This is exactly right. Try `FindInstance[Log[Exp[a/(1 + I)]] != a/(1 + I), a]`